# "No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it."

Tags: python, docker, intellij-idea, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm facing issue for being not creating flask user as for the first time I'm implementing ML project on intellij using airflow and docker.

ERROR 404 is popping up airflow UI

below is my docker file code

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:2.1.0
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0
COPY requirement.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirement.txt
```

my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"

  webserver:
    build: ./dockerfiles
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins

    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

the error that I'm getting:

```
project_p-webserver-1  | [2023-08-11 11:57:30,674] {manager.py:784} WARNING - No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it.
project_p-webserver-1  | [2023-08-11 11:57:30,677] {manager.py:784} WARNING - No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it.
project_p-webserver-1  | [2023-08-11 11:57:30,796] {manager.py:784} WARNING - No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it.
project_p-webserver-1  | [2023-08-11 11:57:30,804] {manager.py:784} WARNING - No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it.
```

I tried different combinations still facing issues can somebody help please.

Comment: Can you share the build log? Theoretically the airflow image should have a step in the entrypoint that does this https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/scripts/docker/entrypoint_prod.sh#L136

Comment: Sorry I'm using docker and airflow for the first time are asking the logs that I get in the intellij terminal after the command docker-compose up --build

or If I'm wrong the you are asking about docker compose that I've already posted as there is no entry point I've created.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some documentation about it here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#creating-admin-user you need to set some env variables for the admin user to be created.

The `environment` part of your webserver could look like this :

```yaml
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE=true
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME=airflow
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD=airflow
```

Comment: I did that and now someother error popped up should I share here?

Comment: It's probably best to start an other topic if the issue is not related to user creation